# Control+left/right arrow shortcut doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I'm trying to change the shortcut for back and forward pages in chrome. Initially to go forward or backward, you can either press command+left/right arrow or command+[/]. I want to make it control+left/right arrow. After going into keyboard -> shortcuts, I made the swap[image]

and macos shows that the swap actually worked in chrome

[image]

But when I try the shortcut it doesn't do anything, and only command+left/right arrow work (so neither command+[/] or control+left/right arrow work)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out after noticing that control+arrows was already mapped by mission control to move between applications left and right. So I simply remapped the mission control shortcuts to use command instead of control and now everything work.

To do this go into keyboard -> shortcuts -> mission control.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oddly, they work for me by default, but only after if I click away the cursor focus from a text input field (I use a chrome addon that puts the focus into the first input field on all pages). There is another addon that supports hotkeys but local to the browser, I can configure that one to overcome this.